# Jenkins Jira steps - Groovy code in Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jira

Seems like `Jira steps` works only in `Scripted pipeline`. How can I make use of `JIRA steps` inside `Declarative pipeline`? I get the error `Unsupported map entry expression for CPS transformation` when I try defining  Jira steps inside pipeline.

```
stages {    
    stage('Create JIRA Ticket'){            
        steps{          
            
            script {
                def jiraserver = "Demo"
                
                def testIssue = [fields [
                        project [id: '10101'],
                        summary: '[Test] Code Scan - $BUILD_NUMBER ',
                        description: 'Automated Pipeline',
                       customfield_1000: 'customValue',
                       issuetype: [id: '10000']]]
                    
                response = jiraNewIssue issue: testIssue
                echo response.successful.toString()
                echo response.data.toString()
                
                jiraAddComment site: 'Demo', idOrKey: 'Test-1', comment: 'Started Unit Tests'
            }
        }               
    }
```

I get the error `WorkflowScript: 42: Unsupported map entry expression for CPS transformation in this context @ line 42, column 17        project [id: '10101'],`

Answer (score 1):

You have several syntax issues on the `testIssue` parameter definition which causes the `Unsupported map entry expression` exception.
The issues is that `fields` and `project` are dictionary keys and should be followed with `:`.
In addition if you wish to interpolate the `BUILD_NUMBER` in the summary use double quotes (`""`).

The following should work:

```groovy
    def testIssue = [fields: [
                        project: [id: '10101'],
                        summary: "[Test] Code Scan - $BUILD_NUMBER",
                        description: 'Automated Pipeline',
                        customfield_1000: 'customValue',
                        issuetype: [id: '10000']]]
```